# access local variable within *ngIf

Tags: angular2-template, primeng

I have a primeng (angular 2) dialog with a dropdown. I want to set focus to the dropdown when the dialog shows. The problem appears to be that my `div` is rendered conditionally.

My code:

```
<p-dialog (onShow)="fe.applyFocus()">
  <div *ngIf="selectedItem">
    <button pButton type="button" (click)="fe.applyFocus()" label="Focus"></button>
    <p-dropdown #fe id="reason" [options]="reasonSelects" [(ngModel)]="selectedReason" ></p-dropdown>
  </div>
</p-dialog>
```

In this code the button works fine, but the onShow() (outside the `*ngIf` div) tells me `fe` is undefined.

How can I access the local variable inside the `*ngIf`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a real pain. Unfortunately, due to the way *ngIf works, it completely encapsulates everything inside (including the tag it's on).

This means anything declared on, or inside, the tag with the ngIf will not be "visible" outside of the ngIf.

And you can't even simply put a @ViewChild in the ts, because on first run it might not be present... So there are 2 known solutions to this problem...

a) You can use @ViewChildren. This will give you a QueryList that you can subscribe to, which will fire off every time the tempalte variable changes (ie. the ngIf turns on or off).

(html template)

```
<div>{{thing.stuff}}</div>
<my-component #thing></my-component>
```

(ts code)

```
@ViewChildren('thing') thingQ: QueryList<MyComponent>;
thing: MyComponent;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.doChanges();
    this.thingQ.changes.subscribe(() => { this.doChanges(); });
}

doChanges() {
    this.thing = this.thingQ.first;
}
```

b) You can use @ViewChild with a setter. This will fire the setter every time the ngIf changes.

(html template)

```
<div>{{thing.stuff}}</div>
<my-component #thing></my-component>
```

(ts code)

```
@ViewChild('thing') set SetThing(e: MyComponent) {
    this.thing = e;
}
thing: MyComponent;
```

Both of these examples should give you a "thing" variable you can now use in your template, outside of the ngIf. You may want to give the ts variable a different name to the template (#) variable, in case there are clashes.

Comment: Ok my original version of the ViewChildren example didn't work - but I've changed it, and now it's working fine :)

Comment: Nice answer. In my case I also had to do `this.cdr.detectChanges();` after 
`this.thing = e` because I was getting `ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked.`

Comment: It is quite tricky and unintuitive, but it DOES work. I'm not sure where the documentation is for how the setter is called on a ViewChild but it's not clear at all. When i moved the setter away from the ViewChild, it never got called, but when its attached to the ViewChild it does work.

Answer (score 2):

You can separate the use of template on NgIf level:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="selectedItem; else elseTemplate">
    <p-dialog (onShow)="fe.applyFocus()">
        <div>
            <button pButton type="button" (click)="fe.applyFocus()" label="Focus"></button>
            <p-dropdown #fe id="reason" [options]="reasonSelects" [(ngModel)]="selectedReason"></p-dropdown>
        </div>
    </p-dialog>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #elseTemplate>
    <p-dialog>
    </p-dialog>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: This is great. I looked everywhere for a proper answer but they were all so complicated. This easily does exactly what is required to use a local variable and the ngIf at the same time. Thank you!

Comment: This doesn't make sense. How do we access `#elseTemplate` or any local template variable inside of it from the typescript component? It didn't work directly referencing it when I tried.

Comment: @TetraDev the question does not mention to access the local variable in typescript

Comment: True, your solution does work for the stated question. Upvoted :-)